# How can I make a graph network from image of granular packing?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, image-processing, image

I have an image from experimental data of granular packing. I need to characterize the packing as a network. The network consist of node (center of granular particle) and edge. Two node are connected if there is a contact point of two granular particle.

I have tried to make a skeletonize, but it doesn't work because there are two (even more than two) node in one particle.

Can I extract the network from this image?[image: granular packing]

Comment: Maybe this can be a starting point for you or for someone who will answer: `img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/78BBP.png"], 
   "Grayscale"];

dt = ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform@MedianFilter[Binarize[img], 3]`. It's easy to get the disk centres from `dt` with `MaxDetect`. I do not have the time to play with this and will not post an answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Another starting point, where the objects being more or less fixed size disks is used ad hoc to measure their centroids as components after some mangling, and those which are close enough to each other are connected in the graph if out of sample of four hundred points along the edge at most four are not "white."

Image is in the variable `img` and plenty of magic constants are employed. (If it's not otherwise obvious, I have to make it explicit: having such hand-picked constants as `0.9`, `40`, `55`, `300`, `0.0025` or even `0.25` or `5` is definitely a weakness, not a strong point of a solution.)

```
(* Perform image manipulation steps, feeding from one to another. *)
(* You can replace a "//" with "// Echo //" to see an intermediate value. *)
MorphologicalBinarize[img, 0.9] // Blur[#, 40] & // 
    Binarize[#, 0.9] & // HitMissTransform[#, DiskMatrix[55]] & // 
  (* Measure component centroids on the manipulated image. *)
  ComponentMeasurements[#, "Centroid"][[All, 2]] & // 
 Function[v, 
  (* Select valid edges from all pairs of components:
     - those whose edge length is less than 300, and
     - at most 4 values of 400 sampled along the edge have a value < 0.25 *)
  Select[Subsets[v, {2}],
     EuclideanDistance @@ # < 300 &&
      Count[Table[Min@PixelValue[img, {t, 1 - t}.#], {t, 0, 1, 0.0025}],
       _?(# < 0.25 &)] < 5 &] // 
   (* Overlay the graph on top of the original image. *)
   Show[img,
     (* Construct a graph object with vertices on component centroids,
        and edges as filtered by the Select expression. *) 
     Graph[v, UndirectedEdge @@@ #, VertexCoordinates -> v, 
      VertexStyle -> Red, VertexSize -> 1/2], ImageSize -> Medium] &]
```

> [image]

Following variant just generates the graph `g`:

```
g = (MorphologicalBinarize[img, 0.9] // Blur[#, 40] & // 
      Binarize[#, 0.9] & // HitMissTransform[#, DiskMatrix[55]] & // 
    ComponentMeasurements[#, "Centroid"][[All, 2]] & // 
   Function[v, 
    Select[Subsets[v, {2}],
       EuclideanDistance @@ # < 300 &&
        Count[Table[Min@PixelValue[img, {t, 1 - t}.#], {t, 0, 1, 0.0025}],
         _?(# < 0.25 &)] < 5 &] // 
     Graph[v, UndirectedEdge @@@ #, VertexCoordinates -> v] &])
```

... on which you can perform graph operations:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[g]
```

> [image]

Comment: Wow, very impressive.

Comment: It is very good and get what I want to do this research. Thank you @kirma 

But as I am not expert in this notation syntax, I hope someone can transalet this syntax into step by step (line by line) notation. Thank you very much.

Comment: And also I need to extract the graph for more exploration in network science, like community detection etc. So can I get that?

Comment: @IqbalRahmadhan I added some commentary in the code, hope it helps a bit. (I'm not able to do more extensive editing at the moment.)

Comment: @kirma thanks for the explanation, it's very helpful. I have another question if you don't mind. 

Can I get the graph data as variabel? If I can, how can I express it in syntax? Because in function `Graph` contains v and #.

Comment: @IqbalRahmadhan Hopefully I have time to add an example later today. I'm a little curious if your problem might actually stem from accidentally removing last `&` from the expression (just before the last closing bracket)...

Comment: @IqbalRahmadhan I updated my answer, does it do what you're after?

Comment: @kirma Oh great! Thank you very much. That's all what I need. And again, thanks for your time, it's very helpful.

Comment: I'll try to generalize this code for other data experimantation condition. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @kirma . I am using your code and it's going very well. But I have some issue about the software so I need to implement the code to Python. Can you help me please for translation the code? Or can I contact you directly (by email maybe). Thanks

Answer (score 9):

This is far from perfect but may serve you as a starter. The main problem is the noise in the lower left corner and the upper right corner of the input image. I was able to get rid of some of it by apllying a `MinFilter`. Also the resulting graph may be postprocessed to remove some artifacts.

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/78BBP.png"], "Grayscale"];
G = MorphologicalGraph[MinFilter[img, 5]]; // AbsoluteTiming
Show[img, G, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Comment: This will work better if you `ImageResize` smaller and then `MorphologicalBinarize`. I get nice results with `MorphologicalGraph[MorphologicalBinarize[ImageResize[i, 250]]]`. (Try varying the amount to resize by also)

Comment: @Carl Lange Good idea. This take nicely care of the mess in the lower left corner. Several disks around the image boundaries get lost, though. Anyways, feell free to post your own solution. This question is definitely about some filtering and parameter tweaking for which I don't find time at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

First, I find the centroids of the disks (this is similar to what Szabolcs does in a comment):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/78BBP.png"];
binarized = Binarize@MeanFilter[img, 10];
distance = ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform[binarized];

centroids = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize[distance, 0.7], "Centroid"][[All, 2]];
HighlightImage[distance, centroids, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Centroids]

Then I guess a disk radius and check how reasonable it is using `HighlightImage`:

```
disks = Disk[#, 115] & /@ centroids;
HighlightImage[
 img,
 Graphics[{White, disks}, Background -> Black]
 ]
```

[image: Disk fit]

It's not perfect, but let's compute the graph anyway:

```
adjacencyMatrix = 
  Outer[EuclideanDistance[#, #2] <= 2 115 &, centroids, centroids, 1];

graph2 = AdjacencyGraph[Boole@adjacencyMatrix, VertexCoordinates -> centroids];
Show[img, graph2, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Graph]

As Szabolcs points out in a comment, `NearestNeighborGraph` can be used as well:

```
Show[
 img,
 NearestNeighborGraph[centroids, {All, 2 115}],
 ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image: Graph using nearest neighbors]

It has problems but there is some promise in this approach. If anyone is able to improve upon this (or if you were already working in this direction), feel free to post it as your own answer.

Comment: An option is `NearestNeighborGraph[points, {All, radius}]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: It is very good. Is there a way that we can use `MorphologicalGraph[]` after get variabel `distance`?

Comment: @IqbalRahmadhan yeah, but I didn't get great results with it.